# Relace part of ItemContainerTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, staticresource

In my WPF application I have several ListViews which all have a similar appearance regarding the ItemContainerTemplate: Each item in the list will have a small image and a text (name). 
The said image depends on the binding to the underlying object: If a image is set in the corresponding property then image of the object is shown. If the underlying object does not have an image set then a default image is shown.
Depending on the ListView the default image is different: For the list of articles an default-article-image is shown, but for the list of customers the default-customer-image is shown.

For all ListViews in my application the ItemContainerTemplate is basically the same, except for the default image. It would be nice if I could use one common ItemContainerTemplate for all ListViews, but how could I replace the default image for each ListView.

My current ItemContainerTemplate looks basically like this:

```
<ItemContainerTemplate x:Key="MyContainerTemplate">
.
.
.
<Image>
 <Image.Style>
  <Style>
   <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="{Binding Image}" />
   <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Image}" Value="{x:Null}">
     <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="{StaticResource Article}" />
    </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
 </Image.Style>
</Image>
.
.
.
</ItemContainerTemplate>
```

How could I use this ItemContainerTemplate for all ListView, but change the 'StaticResource Article' for each one?

Comment: ItemContainerTemplate is actually a DataTemplate?

Comment: Besides that, why don't you simply set an appropriate default value for the items's Image property?

Comment: I know setting a default value directly in the object, however I would find it nicer if it could be done in XAML only. That means: If it can be done...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind the `Image.Source` to the `Tag` `Property` (or a [Attached Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview)) of the `ListView` to set it individually.

To bind to the `Tag` `Property` in your `ItemContainerTemplate` change the Source to this

```
<Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"/>
```

And now the `Image.Source` can be set from the 'outside'

```
<ListView ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource MyContainerTemplate}" Tag="{StaticResource Article}"/>
```

---

**Edit**

A little less hacky way would be to use a custom `Listview` with a `Property` just for setting the default `Image` source.

The custom `ListView` could look like this and is placed in `Your.Namespace`.

```
public class ListViewWithDefaultImage : ListView
{
    public ListViewWithDefaultImage() : base() { }
    public string DefaultImageSource
    {
        get { return (string)this.GetValue(DefaultImageSourceProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(DefaultImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DefaultImageSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DefaultImageSource", typeof(string), typeof(ListViewWithDefaultImage), new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty));
    //Note: its possible to replace String.Empty with a default Path for Default Images
}
```

Additionally the Style must bind to the DefaultImageSource `Property`.

```
<Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="{Binding Path=DefaultImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" />
```

Now it can be used like this

```
xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:Your.Namespace"
.
.
<cc:ListViewWithDefaultImage ItemsSource="{Binding Samples}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource MyContainerTemplate}" DefaultImageSource="{StaticResource Article}"/>
```

Comment: Hmm, not a very nice soltuion, but it works non the less.
I do not mark this as THE solution now, but I'll upvote because it definately works! THANKS!

Comment: No Problem and out of curiosity: What are your concerns to address it as 'not a very nice Solution'? :) Maybe i can improve the Solution upon them.

Comment: I find the usage of the Tag property not very nice in general. It is more of a hack and not easy to read for other developers.